# Show field in a Views row as selected in the option for a custom Views Formatter

Tags: views, 9

I have created a custom Views formatter to make an accordion. Each accordion item is a row. I added a custom field for the user to select which field would be used for the title of the accordion item.

Inside `{% for row in rows %}` how can I get the value of the field chosen in the options? I thought maybe `{{ row.accordion_item_title }}` would work, but it does not.

I have seen [Theming Views in Drupal 8 – Custom Style Plugins](https://www.sitepoint.com/theming-views-in-drupal-8-custom-style-plugins/), which includes a field to select a field, but in this case, the field values are rendered outside of `{% for row in rows %}`.